# datetimepicker not load properly inside asp repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datetimepicker

Below is the markup page of the repeater

```
                 <table>
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeat">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Date:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <userControls:dateTime runat="server" ID="time" AllowEmpty="false"></userControls:dateTime>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </table>
```

I've made the "jquery datetimepicker" a user control so that it can be reused, below is the markup page of the "userControls:dateTime"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              dateFormat: "dd/m/yy",
              yearRange: "-2:+2"
          });

      });
  </script>
<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The problem is:

When I copied `<userControls:dateTime runat="server" ID="time" AllowEmpty="false"></userControls:dateTime>` outside the repeater, it's working properly, but if it's inside the repeater, when the user clicks the textbox, the calender won't show, I haven't got any javascript errors how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute the above query, you actually get the ouput as

```
<element id="datepicker">Some text</element>
```

So, you select the id of the element by using `#`. Which is the basic selector for jQuery and CSS too.

Try this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
```

This will select the element with the id of `datepicker`.